# References between two projects

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have two visual studio Solutions: `DB` and `WFProject`. The second is a Windows Form project.

`DB` contains only one project, DB.
`WFProject` contains two projects : WFProject and DB.

In the project WFProject, I references the DLL of DB, from the `DB` solution.
So the location of the dll : `..\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DB\bin\Debug\DB.dll`

It is on "copyLocal : True".

The problem is : sometimes, it does not found the dll. I have to remove and re add it on my references.

I clean, and build, and I got this bug really often.

Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need reference the DB as a project rather than pointing directly to it's compiled DLL.  This will make Visual Studio do what you want.

Comment: But why can't I reference the compiled DLL, if I set it to copyLocal = True in my WF project? It exist, so, the project build and do a local copy of the DLL no?

Comment: it ceases to exist when you clean the solution but only rebuild this one project... or it will sometimes cease to exist if visual studio has decided to rebuild both projects in parallel.  projects in the same solution should reference each other *as projects* so the tools can do their job correctly

Comment: Ok, so when it doesn't found it, that's because he is working on it. Thank you.